# reassigning a function to variable on javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a Vector3 function on javascript

```
    function Vector(basex,basey,basez) {
    if(!(this instanceof Vector))
        return new Vector (x,y,z);
    this.x=basex;
    this.y=basey;
    this.z=basez;
}

Vector.prototype.toString=function(){
    return '(' + this.x + ', '+  this.y + ', ' + this.z +   ')';
}


s= new Vector(1,2,3); //(1,2,3)
```

however, when I try to reassign s with

```
s=Vector(3,4,5)
```

I get 
ReferenceError at line NaN: x is not defined

If I use

```
 s=new Vector(3,4,5)
```

It works, but is this the correct way to reassign my variable?
I tried to look up the web for some "reassigning my variable" but only fond that a primitive vars can be reassigned

```
var n=3;
n=5;
```

But nothing about functions.
Any headups?

Comment: (Working with immutable values is usually much easier and safer. I'd go with a single assignment, and no reassignments, in 99% of my code. Just saying.)

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

```
if(!(this instanceof Vector))
    return new Vector (x,y,z);
```

The variables `x`, `y`, and `z` are not defined.  You probably meant to use the values which were passed to the function:

```
if(!(this instanceof Vector))
    return new Vector (basex,basey,basez);
```

Comment: couldn't feel more dumb than I do now... missed this one